# Python : Extract one string from 100 lines of text

Tags: python, regex, logging

1. I need to extract a particular string from 100 lines of log data. I
   tried split and then tried to get the needed string but couldn't
   succeed. Any suggestions/help appreciated. Thanks!

   In the log below, I would like to extract the highlighted part, that
   is
   **zqn.2005- 04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0000**  (its in line 57)

   ```
   1         Out[19]:
   2         {'portstatus': {'errors': {'busy_errors': '0',
   3         'checkcondition_errors': '0',
   4         'compare_errors': '0',
   5         'ioc_errors': '0',
   6         'notready_errors': '0',
   7         'read_errors': '0',
   8         'read_retries': '0',
   9         'scsi_errors': '0',
   10         'test_errors': '0',
   11         'timeout_errors': '0',
   12         'write_errors': '0',
   13         'write_retries': '0'},
   14         'net_counters': {'RxBytes': '148476788547060',
   15         'RxCompressed': '0',
   16         'RxDrop': '96188',
   17         'RxErrs': '0',
   18         'RxFIFO': '0',
   19         'RxFrame': '0',
   20         'RxMulticast': '259513',
   21         'RxPFCPause': '0',
   22         'RxPackets': '77165581759',
   23         'RxStandardPause': '0',
   24         'TxBytes': '20440169002909',
   25         'TxCompressed': '0',
   26         'TxDrop': '0',
   27         'TxErrs': '0',
   28         'TxFIFO': '0',
   29         'TxFrame': '0',
   30         'TxMulticast': '0',
   31         'TxPFCPause': '0',
   32         'TxPackets': '55075507366',
   33         'TxStandardPause': '5349727',
   34         'net_avgriops': '0',
   35         'net_avgrrate': '0.00',
   36         'net_avgtiops': '0',
   37         'net_avgtrate': '0.00',
   38         'net_riops': '0',
   39         'net_rrate': '0.00',
   40         'net_tiops': '0',
   41         'net_trate': '0.00'},
   42         'perfdata': {'avg_oiocnt': '0',
   43         'avgiops': '0',
   44         'avgriops': '0',
   45         'avgrrate': '0.00',
   46         'avgtrate': '0.00',
   47         'avgwiops': '0',
   48         'avgwrate': '0.00',
   49         'iops': '0',
   50         'max_oiocnt': '509',
   51         'oiocnt': '0',
   52         'riops': '0',
   53         'rrate': '0.00',
   54         'trate': '0.00',
   55         'wiops': '0',
   56         'wrate': '0.00'},
   57         'status': {'initiator0_iqn': 'zqn.2005- 04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0000',
   58         'initiator10_iqn': 'zqn.2005-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0010',
   59         'initiator11_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0011',
   60         'initiator12_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0012',
   61         'initiator13_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0013',
   62         'initiator14_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0014',
   63         'initiator15_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0015',
   64         'initiator16_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0016',
   65         'initiator17_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0017',
   66         'initiator18_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0018',
   67         'initiator19_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0019',
   68         'initiator1_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0001',
   69         'initiator20_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0020',
   70         'initiator21_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0021',
   71         'initiator22_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0022',
   72         'initiator23_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0023',
   73         'initiator24_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0024',
   74         'initiator25_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0025',
   75         'initiator26_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0026',
   76         'initiator27_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0027',
   77         'initiator28_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0028',
   78         'initiator29_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0029',
   79         'initiator2_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0002',
   80         'initiator30_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0030',
   81         'initiator31_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0031',
   82         'initiator32_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0032',
   83         'initiator33_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0033',
   84         'initiator34_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0034',
   85         'initiator35_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0035',
   86         'initiator36_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0036',
   87         'initiator37_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0037',
   88         'initiator38_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0038',
   89         'initiator39_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0039',
   90         'initiator3_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0003',
   91         'initiator40_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0040',
   92         'initiator41_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0041',
   93         'initiator42_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0042',
   94         'initiator43_iqn': 'iqn.2003-04.com.sanblaze:virtualun.init74-2.initiator-00000000-0043',
   95         'mode': 'Init',
   96         'numinitiators': '50',
   97         'numtargets': '0',
   98         'port': '0',
   99         'portwwnn': '90:e2:ba:82:92:1c',
   100         'portwwpn': '90:e2:ba:82:92:1c',
   101         'speed': '10G',
   102         'state': 'Online',
   103         'topo': 'iSCSI'},
   104         'sympn': '-',
   ```

Comment: If the dictionary is called `lookup` then: `lookup['status']['initiator0_iqn']`

Comment: Also, does the language used matter? Does the solution have to be Python, or is the output from Python and any language will do to get the output?

Comment: @Addison I just need to get that string, I would like to copy it to some other variable. It needs to be in Python.

Comment: Is that output suppose to be json or a json like object?  If so you might be able to json.loads() to convert that to a python dictionary. Otherwise since you've stated you don't want to import anything, read each line, split at the : ... The left side becomes the key and the right the value... or iterate over every line and use an if statement if  "line".find(substring) > -1: then this must be my string... or since you seem to know the parts your looking for use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the string is in dictionary format (correct me if I'm wrong), so you could try converting it to one. Then you won't need regex.

```
import ast
your_dict = ast.literal_eval(your_string)
```

Then what you want would be:

```
your_dict['status']['initiator0_iqn']
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way by not importing any libs?

Comment: `ast` should come with python on your system. But if you don't want to use that, you can convert the string to json using `json.loads`. However you would have to `import json` which is another library (though it is also included).

Comment: Ultimately you'll want to convert the string to a dictionary, as that's the fastest and most logical way to do this. If you have the object as a dictionary at any point, then you won't have to import any libraries.